# Cant get 'UseOAuthBearerTokens' to work with Owin and Identity RTM

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

I use

```
 app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

and

```
var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{

    TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Token"),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider<CampusDaysUser>(PublicClientId, IdentityManagerFactory, CookieOptions)
};
```

But url http://example.com/Token/ returns error:

> The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Token"),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider<CampusDaysUser>(PublicClientId, IdentityManagerFactory, CookieOptions)
    };
```

Need to set allow http now to get it working. Read the comments, this should be done in development only. **Production you should get a certificate and use SSL**.

Comment: Isn't this a dangerous advice? If I understand correctly this allows unsecured communication to obtain the token, which I cannot imagine is good for the security.

Comment: AllowInsecureHttp is only intended for development purposes.  In a production system the recommendation is to use SSL to ensure tokens are not being passed in the clear.

Comment: What joe said. I will update my answer to state this also. I just needed it to work in development.